# Create An Object With A Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: python, web-applications, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I initialize a **group object with the list of members that are part of the group (and the users have to be aware of the groups that they are a part of)**?

Users have many groups. Groups have many users.

I have also tried an `add_to_group` method in the User class, but that didn't really work out.

This is my first time dealing with a many-to-many relationship, so I haven't figured out how to do it yet, and all SO posts refer to query many-to-many relationships rather than creating objects that use them.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = False, nullable = False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True, nullable = False)
    fb_id = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True, nullable = False)
    groups = db.relationship('Groups', secondary=groups, backref=db.backref('User', lazy='dynamic'))

groups = db.Table('groups',
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Group.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
)

class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Group'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, mutable=True)

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_updated = datetime.utcnow();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first parameter of `db.backref()` is the name the backref attribute should take, not the name of the mapped class.  So, for consistency in your case, you'd probably want to change it from `User` to `users`.  That would create an attribute called `users` on each instance of the `Group` class.

Comment: Also, the first parameter of `db.relationship` _is_ the name of the class on the other side of the relationship, so there you'll want to replace `Groups` with `Group`.

Comment: OK thanks for the tips. Will make appropriate changes in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy, many-to-many relations are modeled as attributes whose values are lists.

```
u = User()
g = [Group(), Group(), Group()]

u.groups = g
```

You can also alter the list in-place:

```
g1 = Group()
u.groups.append(g)
```

The other side of the relationship would work in the same way:

```
g.users.append(User())
```

When you alter one side of a many-to-many relationship, SQLAlchemy keeps the other side up-to-date—in other words, if you remove a `User` from a `Group`'s `users` list, then that `Group` will no longer appear in that `User`'s `groups` list.

Comment: Ok thanks. To be honest, I had actually figured this out by reading SQLAlchemy documentation rather than Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation (which I had read before posting) while I was waiting for someone to respond. But thanks for the help!